# Valgrind blocks are definitely lost in loss record

Tags: c, valgrind

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my valgrind debugging. I am learning this valgrind slowly.

debug:

```
==1701== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1701==     in use at exit: 390 bytes in 12 blocks
==1701==   total heap usage: 59 allocs, 47 frees, 1,097 bytes allocated
==1701==
==1701== 39 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 12
==1701==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1701==    by 0x401246: songToString (song.c:147)
==1701==    by 0x40083C: main (songtest.c:52)
==1701==
```

Code (songToString function):

```
char *songToString(const song *s)
{
    char *sstr = NULL ;
    char *st = NULL ;
    char *sa = NULL ;
    char *tt = NULL ;
    int len = 0 ;

    st = songGetTitle(s) ;
    sa = songGetArtist(s) ;

    // calculate the total string length needed.
    len = strlen("Title: ") + strlen(st) +
                  strlen("  Artist: ") + strlen(sa) + 1 ;

    if (NULL != s->lastPlayed)
    {
        tt = mtimeToString(s->lastPlayed) ;
        len += strlen(" at ") + strlen(tt) ;
    }

    // allocate enough space for the song
    sstr = malloc( len ) ;

    sprintf(sstr, "Title: %s  Artist: %s", st, sa) ;

    if (NULL != s->lastPlayed)
    {
        sstr = strcat(sstr, " at ") ;
        sstr = strcat(sstr, tt) ;
    }

    free(sa) ;
    free(st) ;
    free(tt) ;
    return sstr ;
}
```

In songToString, line 147 is `sstr = malloc( len ) ;`

in songTest (line 52):

```
char * sstr = songToString( song1 ) ;
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`valgrind` is showing you where the leaked memory was *allocated*, but the actual bug has to be tracked to where that memory *ends up*.

Obviously after you assign to `sstr` in `main`, you never `free` that.

Comment: So `free(sstr)` after `char *sstr = songToString(song1)` (that is located in main)?

Comment: @user4127382 right. Of course, you have to make sure that that's after you're doing using it.

Answer (score -6):

@o11c
You gave wrong advice.
See link:
http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Another solution is to have the function return the pointer:

```
int *f()
{
    static int dummy = 5;
    return &dummy;
}

...

int *ip = f();
```